# Managing script folders in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am new at GEE and I just created a folder named Tutorials to save my first scripts. Like that:

> users/GEEDataJosep/Tutorials

Right now I am using the acquired knowledge to work with my projects and I am only able to save that scripts to that `'Tutorials'` folder.

Is there any way to manage that folders and create a new one for real projects?

Answer (score 2):

There is a red NEW button to do it close to the search bar in the scripts of the code editor. As follows:

[image]